# A better way in checking if datagridview contains integer?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, integer

So currently I have a datagridview and i'm importing an excel file into it. Columns 3-6 should contain numbers.

This is my code as of now .. but there has to be a quicker and more efficient way of checking for number?
maybe something with isinteger..
Also this only checks for one column..

the isFound variable is a bool to check if a certain string is in the imported excel file.
so for example, if the excel file contains the word "data" in a certain cell, it would in turn mark isFound = true.

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            If Not row.Cells("F3").Value Is DBNull.Value Then

                If (isFound) Then
                    'MessageBox.Show("Data Exists!")
                    Select Case row.Cells("F3").Value
                    'checks for all numbers 0 - 9999
                        Case "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" .. "9999"

                            'All pass verification, Do nothing
                        Case Else
                            'Point out the wrong value 
                            row.Cells("F3").Style.BackColor = Color.Red
                                                    End Select
                Else
                    '    MessageBox.Show("Not a number!")
                End If
            End If
        Next
```

Comment: You should be using [`Integer.TryParse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse). Side note: better to use `IsNot` instead of `Not ... Is`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Integer.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx). It takes a string and a number. If it can convert it properly, it returns true and put the value inside the number variable.

```
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        If Not row.Cells("F3").Value Is DBNull.Value Then

            If (isFound) Then
                Dim cellNumber As Integer

                If Integer.TryParse(row.Cells("F3").Value, cellNumber) AndAlso cellNumber >= 0 AndAlso cellNumber <= 9999 Then
                    'All pass verification, Do nothing
                Else
                    'Point out the wrong value 
                    row.Cells("F3").Style.BackColor = Color.Red
                End If
            Else
                '    MessageBox.Show("Not a number!")
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

An other idea would be to create a function that does all the check and just call that function instead.

```
Private Function IsInRange(ByVal numberAsString As String, ByVal min As Integer, ByVal max As Integer) As Boolean

    Dim number As Integer

    If Not Integer.Parse(numberAsString, number) Then
        Return False
    End If

    If number < min Or number > max Then
        Return False
    End If

    Return True
End Function
```

...

```
            If IsInRange(row.Cells("F3").Value, 0, 9999) Then
                'All pass verification, Do nothing
            Else
                'Point out the wrong value 
                row.Cells("F3").Style.BackColor = Color.Red
            End If
```

Answer (score -1):

This solution isn't perfect but still better... I could have used IsNumeric, but this allows doubles. You could use IsNumeric andalso cint(cdbl(s))=cdlb(s)

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    If Not row.Cells("F3").Value Is DBNull.Value Then
        If (isFound) Then
            'MessageBox.Show("Data Exists!")
            dim s  as string =  row.Cells("F3").Value
            for i as integer = 0 to 9
                s= strings.replace(s,cstr(i),"")
            next
            if strings.len(  row.Cells("F3").Value)<=4 andalso s="" then
                'it IS an integer <=9999
            Else
                'Point out the wrong value 
                row.Cells("F3").Style.BackColor = Color.Red

        Else
            '    MessageBox.Show("Not a number!")
        End If

    Next
```

edited:
alternative:

```
  dim s  as string = row.Cells("F3").Value
  if isnumeric(s) andalso cdbl(s)=cint(cdbl(s)) andalso cint(s)<=9999 then
                'it IS an integer <=9999
```

Comment: `Int32.TryParse()` would also work.  This method returns a true or false value depending upon the success or failure of converting the value to an integer.

Comment: I was thinking isnumber, but I couldn't figure out what to put in the parenthesis. 
tryparse was the same .

I understand your answer @Pierre. just looking at it and logically I see what you are saying , thank you

Comment: `TryParse(s, r)` requires two arguments.  `s` is a string that you are testing as an integer, while `r` is an integer variable that will be used to store the result of the test/conversion.  If you need to refer back to the result you can declare an integer variable to be used as `r` and reference it at any time that it is within scope.  If you only need to to know the result at the time you call the `TryParse()` method, then you can pass `Nothing` as the arguement for `r`.

Comment: @Pierre What is the Select Case doing? I have never seen it used that way.

Comment: @mary : that's old, it's just a bad copy paste, makes no sense. :(

Comment: @Pierre Wow, a responnse to a 2 year old comment. I don't think it was you to begin with. Visual Studio likes to add Case to and Select even if it is in an sql statement or a linq expression. Very annoying. :-)

Comment: @Mary : I think I just copied badly OP's code and didn't read it again ^^' (I've been coming more rarely here lately)